# How do I extract sql query line from log file using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, logging

I have stored log file data in string.

log file Data:

```
testOut_Log: START RequestId: 13b73ed9-b101-11e8-8619-91946b18fd8a Version: $LATEST
2018-09-05 11:44:41 <13b73ed9-b101-11e8-8619-91946b18fd8a> INFO  UpcDaoImpl:QUERY : SELECT apn, epc, rpc_fmt_cd FROM tbl_data WHERE apn= '43781661' OR apn= '63535011' OR apn= '19870' OR apn = '1023313'
2018-09-05 11:44:42 <13b73ed9-b101-11e8-8619-91946b18fd8a> INFO  addpcDaoImpl:RPT
```

Require only Query:

```
SELECT apn, epc, rpc_fmt_cd FROM tbl_data WHERE apn= '43781661' OR apn= '63535011' OR apn= '19870' OR apn = '1023313'
```

Code I have tried:

String myQuery = testOutput_Log.substring(testOutput_Log.indexOf("QUERY : "));
        System.out.println(myQuery);

output:
myQuery:

QUERY :  SELECT apn, epc, rpc_fmt_cd FROM tbl_data WHERE apn= '43781661' OR apn= '63535011' OR apn= '19870' OR apn = '1023313'
2018-09-05 14:43:51 <1b214074-b11a-11e8-af80-d5e640140a71> INFO  aaaapcDaoImpl:RPT

Comment: Can you please provide any code you've tried?

Comment: It seems you can search each line for `QUERY`. Then you can subString that line using something like `string.subString(string.indexOf("QUERY : "):`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Below code is work for me:

String myQuery = testOutput_Log.substring(testOutput_Log.indexOf("QUERY : "));
        System.out.println("myQuery: \n"+ myQuery);
        String myQuery2 = myQuery.substring(myQuery.indexOf("SELECT"), myQuery.indexOf("\n"));
        System.out.println("myQuery2: \n"+ myQuery2);